# Omitting certain style string labels in QGIS 3 rule-based labeling

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, string

I’m labeling airport taxiways. The taxiway labels are all strings but they tend to be one of three varieties and I would only like to show one of those. I’ve been trying to mess around with Rule-Based Labeling for this layer and haven’t had any success yet.

The strings can be one of the following format:

1. **A, B, C...AA,BB,CC… A1, B1** etc
2. **A.B, A.B.C, A1.B2.A,** etc <— the use of the “.” In these makes them different from the first variety
3. **$UNK**<— this is when the feature has no known value but the field must still be filled in

Below I've attached an example of what the labels look like in QGIS. 
[image]

I would like to only show the labels of the first variety. 
I think the best way would be to create a rule that doesn’t print anything that equals $UNK or has “.” in it. I’m just unsure of how to write that as a rule or even if rule-based labeling is the right way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

In the label expression settings you can set up a case statement that basically states

```
case 
when label in ('list', 'of', 'values', 'to', 'omit') then '' 
else 'label_column' 
end
```

You wouldn't need to set a rule for every pattern you want to omit, and you can also use LIKE statements as well, which would extend the above to something like:

```
case 
when label_column in ('list', 'of', 'values', 'to', 'omit') then '' 
when label_column like 'BADVALUE%' THEN ''
else 'label_column' 
end
```

The case statement is converting all the labels in your IN or LIKE statements to '' (nothing), otherwise, using the existing value in the label_column

Answer (score 1):

To add onto @DPSSpatial's reply you could use an expression as a data-defined override for the 'Show label' option under the Label Rendering tab (see screenshot - click on the circled button and select Edit... then paste one of the below expressions adapted to your data)

[image]

A simple expression for your case would be: `"label_column" NOT LIKE '%.%' AND "label_column" != '$UNK'`

This filters out all labels with a full stop in them as well as any matching `'$UNK'`

Another approach is to use a regex expression to only match labels that have only alphanumeric characters (which excludes the `$` and `.` characters in the labels you don't want). An example for your case would be: `regexp_match("label_column",'^[\\w]+$')`.

This matches any combination of one or more alphanumeric and whitespace characters (`[\\w]+`) that are the only contents between the beginning and end of the string (`^` and `$` in regex)